# How to pass multidimensional array in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have try to pass the multidimensional array to view. But when I try to print It will give me error. Below are the code and error.

Controller File:

```
foreach($countrygroup as $val){
        //$userArr[] = $val->userid;
        $users =  DB::table('timelines')->where('id', '=', $val->userid)->first();
        $userArr[$val->userid]['name'] = $users->name;//$users->name;
        $userArr[$val->userid]['avatar'] = $users->avatar_id;
        //$userArr[$val->userid]['image']=$users->image;            
    }
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($userArr); die();
      return $theme->scope('groups/country', compact('userArr','trending_tags','countrygroupnamee'))
      ->render();
```

Blade File Code:

```
@foreach($userArr as $users)
    <h2>{{ $users}}</h2>                                                                
 @endforeach
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Querying database in foreach loop? Ouch...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blade template tags `{{ }}` are replaced with an `echo()`. You can't echo an array. You need to get the string out of the array that you want to display, for example:

```
@foreach($userArr as $users)
    <h2>{{ $users['name'] }}</h2>                                                                
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks @jeremy Harris